# How to ask in email conversation if there are 'any updates' or 'any news'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

How do I ask for 'an update' for an email on which I haven't received any response for several days, even weeks.

Answer (score 2):

You could say `Gibt es etwas Neues bezüglich...` which is something like `Is there any news about...`.

Comment: This is a standard phrase one can use to ask e.g. if you asked for something and want to know later if there has been any progress in the matter. Literally it means "Is there anything new about/regarding ..."

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not ask for an update, I just tell that I haven't received an answer yet.

> Sehr geehrter Herr Kowalski,
>
> auf meine Mail vom 15.07.2017 habe ich noch keine Antwort bekommen.
>
> Freundliche Grüße
>   Hans-Hermann Vogel

Usually I append the text of the original mail.

Comment: Das ist schon ein bisschen unhöflich und sollte ohne Kontext nicht so empfohlen werden.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Den Text halte ich für neutral, unhöflich ist es, wenn eine Mail zu lange ohne Antwort bleibt. Daher sollte die Erinnerung auch nicht zu höflich sein. Probiere es aus, in der Regel hast du innerhalb von drei Tagen eine Antwort, und keine unhöfliche.